# How can I find all the columns available in UniProt.ws package for R?

Tags: r, bioconductor, uniprot, rstudio

I am trying to find the subcellular localization of my 10,000 proteins using UniProt.ws package for R. However, I am unable to find all the columns available for query.

I used another package named Bioconductor which had easy way to lookup all the columns available using COLUMNS(org.Hs.eg.db)

I tried reading the documentation and couldn't find anything which can output subcellular localization. I am new to this field, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `UniProt.ws` [manual](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/UniProt.ws/man/UniProt.ws.pdf):

> `columns` shows which kinds of data can be returned for the
>   `UniProt.ws` object.

So, you will need to go over the output of `columns(your_uniprotws_object)` if it includes the data type you are looking for.

And [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/how-to-retrieve-the-subcellular-location-info-from-uniprot) is a related question.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me now with this code:
`up <- UniProt.ws(taxId=9606)`
`keys <- c("4957","81551")`
`columns <- c("PDB","GENES","SUBCELLULAR-LOCATIONS")`
`select(up, keys, columns, kt)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a small sample of the proteins you are looking for and what you have tried so far in R using Uniprot.ws ? (including output of it), it could be helpful to identify your problem and how to solve it.

Personally, I would rather consider Bioconductor as a platform for providing R packages dedicated to bioinformatics than a package to analyze data (but it's my opinion, maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: I have 10000 proteins which I am looking for sub-cellular localization. I tried to find the columns available in UniProt.ws using COLUMNS(UniProt.ws) but it didn't work. Finally, I looked into Bioconductor as you said and found the answer. https://support.bioconductor.org/p/78380/ . res <- select(up, "P35579", "SUBCELLULAR-LOCATIONS", "UNIPROTKB")